# the razor view is not displaying a navigation property value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have the following action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(int questionid, Answer a)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
        repository.AddAnswer(a);
             repository.Save();
             return PartialView("_details",a);
            }
            return View(a);
```

and the folloiwng _details partila view:-

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Answer_Description.description)
    </td>
    <td>
     @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
    new { id = Model.AnswersID },
      new AjaxOptions
      {
          Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?",
          HttpMethod = "Post",
          UpdateTargetId = Model.AnswersID.ToString()
                    })


    </td>
    </tr>
```

**the problem that i am facing is that the `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Answer_Description.description)` value is not being displayed automatically after an ajx call unless i refresh the web page., so what might be the problme?**

Comment: the reason i see is that the `UpdateTargetId` has the value something like `modelname.answerid`but in actuality the rendered id for the answer description is something like `Model.Answer_Description.description`

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect a lazy loading problem (hard to be sure with the infos you give, but)...

As Model.Description seems to be a primitive (string) Property, but Answer_Description.description is a primitive property of a *navigation property*.

Are you sure that the Answer_Description is correctly loaded ?

Edit : to be more precise : your action receives an Answer : does it have the Answer_Description.description when passed ?
If no, you should get the Answer_Description from database before returning View...

Comment: thanks for yuor reply, i do not know how i can check if it is loaded succsfully or not ,, but if i refresh the page the Answer_Description  will be displayed succsfully...

Comment: make a try : put a debug point in your controller : go inside your "Answer a", and check for Model.Answer_Description, to see description.
If it's null, or if it works when u debug this way, that's a lazy loading problem, and you should load explicitly the Answer_Description for your Answer before returning the view

Comment: thanks for r reply, the problem that i usally perform the Eager loading by using .Include when looping through the objects or in similar senarios; but i can determine how i can apply the Include in my case? BR